# javascript function not getting executed

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, onload-event

I want to execute a javascript function in an external js file when the page is loaded. This is the code in the jsp file where the function is called from, I placed it at the bottom of the jsp

```
<%-- Begins countdown --%>
<script src="/pub/scripts/counter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=startCountdown;
</script>
```

this is the function in the js file

```
function startCountdown() {
var TIMEOUT = 900000; 
var COUNT_BACK = 3;   
setTimeout("displayWarning("+COUNT_BACK+")", TIMEOUT);
}
```

when the page loads in the browser I see that the script is loaded but the startCountdown function never gets executed. How can I make this work?

Comment: how do you know `startCountdown` never gets executed? Maybe it is, but `displayWarning` is broken. And this isn't going to count down. It's going to be invoked once after `900` seconds... so you need to wait that long for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `<body onload="startCountdown()">` in your html to ensure that the page must load completely before executing the script.

Comment: That's he's already doing via `window.onload`. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.onload=startCountdown;` to `window.onload=startCountdown();` and use `defer`

```
<%-- Begins countdown --%>
<script defer src="/pub/scripts/counter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script defer type="text/javascript">
window.onload=startCountdown();
</script>
this is the function in the js file

var startCountdown = function() {
var TIMEOUT = 900000; 
var COUNT_BACK = 3;   
setTimeout("displayWarning("+COUNT_BACK+")", TIMEOUT);
};
```

Comment: Adding `()` would be incorrect. And `defer` isn't really going to change anything.